# Failure to sign one page of declaration in printed UK visa application

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas, applications

I just submitted my visa application for the UK (6 months, general visitor). I only signed and dated on page 2 (declaration). I just figured out that it has a second declaration page (usually page 10) which is the same as page 2 and I forgot to sign.

So my questions are:

- Does this lead to a refusal?
- Is one signature is okay since both declaration pages (2 and 10) are exactly the same?
  [image]

Comment: I can't find the QA on the site where it said one of the reasons for the interview is exactly to give an opportunity to fix inconsequential little mistakes like this.

Comment: I agree with chx, I dont think they will call me for interview. Do you think that they will overlook it if other things is ok?

Comment: It doesn't make sense. Which form(s) did you fill out?  The application requires a single signature and that's in Part 10, Declaration.  Look on the first page of the form where it tells the form ID. Or if you used the internet, which site did you use? Also, have you had your biometrics  yet?

Comment: It is the printed version of online applicaton form. I filled online at visa4uk.fco.gov.uk. The page 2 is the same as page 10. I have added the picture.

Comment: Yes, I have submitted all the documents. The status now is with UK Visas and Immigration office

Comment: It looks more like a buggy print job. There's only one declaration, not two.

Comment: Hi Gayot, I asked my friend who make an application few months ago. His online application form also has 2 pages of declaration like me. maybe the new online system will generate 2 declarations for some reasons.:( but from what you said, do you think 1 signatures will be ok? Since they're both exactly the same

Comment: I would ignore it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just so this question has an answer, I am copying Gayot's comments into an answer:

> It looks more like a buggy print job. There's only one declaration, not two.
>
> I would ignore it.

Comment: +1 I agree. They are certainly not going to refuse and if they decide to *reject* it as invalid they will send it back and get it signed. Honestly, can anyone think of why a VAF form would have two identical pages? No they can't. It's a printer bug or end-user malfunction.