# Signature option not available on UK visa form

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas

I have completed my application for the UK visa and planning to send it to the British consulate in New York. At several places I have read that "sign the visa application form" but there isn't a single place in the visa application where a signature is required. There was a signature needed only at one place in the application checklist.

So I am wondering whether I should sign my application randomly at the end or was "sign the visa application" something done in the past but not modified in the literature?

Answer (score 8):

> There was a signature needed only at one place in the application checklist.

**That was it**. You only have to sign the checklist. Even at a VAC you are asked to only sign the checklist.

That checklist is custom built for the applicant by a computer program, 
 technically it is a part of the application and signing that checklist means signing the application.

The old format form [does have a declaration](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/82388/failure-to-sign-one-page-of-declaration-in-printed-uk-visa-application) to sign, the new one has it on the checklist only.

Comment: Do we still need to send a print out of the application form along with the checklist and the documents or only the checklist?

Comment: Yes the application form still needs to be printed and sent.

Comment: Thank you! I've been so confused during my whole visa application process.

Answer (score 2):

I went for the biometric today for UK transit visa in the US. VFS site says that print the checklist for the biometric and sign in front of the officer. The officer at ASC(US) did not ask for the checklist and said that they just do biometric - fingerprinting and facial photo.

As such the checklist, is not signed by the officer. I have read few other posts, and believe that checklist is for reference purpose, and the application form is also not required to be signed. Unfortunately, VFS has not clearly mentioned anywhere, and the process still continues to be confusing new applicants. These forums are helpful to take a wise decision in such matters.

In my current application, I have

1. Printed the application form (not signed) and sent to VFS, NY
2. Not sent the signed Checklist to VFS and also not uploaded.

If I were to redo the application, I would

1. Print and send the application form (without signature)
2. Tick the checklist options, and sign it and send it to VFS center in NY